# visual studio crashed when open a .aspx

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

when i open a aspx page that have master page the visual studio crashed. no erorr or any thing only show Not Responding in title bar of visual studio . no problem when i in markup but crashed when i go in designer . only pages that have master page is crashed .visual studio 2010 ultimate.

Comment: Delete and re-create the page

Comment: Have you added any references to the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you to find cause of issue.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534902/visual-studio-2010-crashes-when-editing-a-master-page-or-aspx-code-behind